# run scp from ipython notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is it possible to run `scp` from the ipython notebook? I am simply doing

```
!scp server://remote_file .
```

What I get is an output in the notebook

```
Password:
```

but I can't write any password.

Comment: scp requires input over stdin. I don't think there's an easy way to feed a password, without hardcoding it somewhere. Simple workaround: deploy a ssh-key on the target machine, then `scp` will work without asking for a passphrase.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [public key authentication](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) between your machine and the remote server
so you dont have to give a password every time you download something or even login. The remote server identifies your machine and downloads the data.

This works in ipython notebooks and the file is downloaded.
Then you can use

!scp server://remote_file .

Comment: this not answer the question.

Comment: I disagree, @RuggeroTurra.  If you set up a public key on the remote server, you will no longer need to type a password into the jupyter notebook and can !scp server://remote_file in a jupyter notebook cell.  This answers your question.